# Creating code on a worksheet to copy and paste cells in various columns

Tags: excel

How to create VBA code on a worksheet to copy and paste cells (col2 is first name, col3 is last name) from two columns to create an e-mail address in the first column with the first name then a . (period), followed by the last name then to paste identical information (e-mail domain) after the @ sign

to result in

first.last@domain.com

Answer (score 1):

I don't think something as simple as this requires using VBA.

Lets say your first names are in column `A`, last names in column `B` and you want this email format in column `C` simply write the following in `C2` and a copy the formula by dragging the fill handle till the end of your data.

```
=CONCATENATE(A2,".", B2,"@domain.com")
```